# On local active directory can't nest group memberOf another group

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory, windows-xp, windows-authentication

I am trying to create a scenario of file system permission to test a software that I am currently developing. In this scenario I want a group be a memberOf another group. However on the global domain-controller this works and is also a best practise in Windows (as far as I am concerned).

But if I try to nest a group into another group on my local machine it just allows me to add users or integrated security principals (not sure if this is the right translation).

Is there a way to possibly overcome this restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only nest certain types of groups in other groups.  Local groups cannot contain other local groups.  See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974815?wa=wsignin1.0

For AD group nesting rules, this article should help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776499(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have an Idea how to overcome this "issue"?

Comment: Can you build a domain controller & AD in a local virtual machine and test where no harm can come to the production network?

Comment: Hi thank you again. I think to create a new DomainController and AD will be the only chance to work around this issue. If anybody is aware of another solution I would be happy to hear it.